# Passing Models into other components

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm debugging an issue where an ArrayCollection on a model isn't getting updated in the UI (even though I see it in the new data).

I was wondering if passing that model into other components, i.e. the top level component, causes problems.

For example, here's my model in the top level:

```
[Bindable]
        private var meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel;
```

Now here I am passing it into a component in the same class:

```
<meetingViewStack:MeetingViewStack id="mainPanelContainer"
                                   newAttachmentsList="{meetingInfo.newAttachmentList}"
                                   meetingInfo="{meetingInfo}"
                                   currentState="{getPanelState(currentState)}"
                                   inCreateMeeting="false" 
                                   includeIn="runSinglePanel, runDoublePanel"
                                   height="100%"
                                   width="100%"
                                   />
```

And here's how I have that property declared in that MeetingViewStack component:

```
[Bindable] 
        public var meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel = MeetingInfoModel.getInstance();
```

Should binding work correctly in the MeetingViewStack? Even though that property was passed into it by another component.

I mean I really don't have a compelling need to pass it in. It's a model and I can declare it right there.

Thanks for any helpful tips!

UPDATE:

I have verified that the setter gets called when I updated the meetingInfo property. However, it does not get called when I update an array collection in the meetingInfo model, i.e.

```
meetingInfo.docsAndAttachmentsList.sort = nameSort;
        meetingInfo.docsAndAttachmentsList.refresh();
```

How can I get that to work? That's what I'm really looking for.

Here's the MeetingInfoModel class:

```
package com.fmr.transporter.model
```

{
    import com.fmr.transporter.events.CustomEvent;
    import com.fmr.transporter.events.xmppServicesEvents.XMPPContactsLoadedEvent;
    import com.fmr.transporter.services.httpservices.UserServices;
    import com.fmr.transporter.services.xmppservices.XMPPServices;
    import com.fmr.transporter.util.util;
    import com.fmr.transporter.vo.ContactVO;
    import com.fmr.transporter.vo.MeetingVO;
    import com.fmr.transporter.vo.ParticipantVO;

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.events.CollectionEvent;

import org.igniterealtime.xiff.data.im.RosterItemVO;

[Bindable]
public final class MeetingInfoModel extends EventDispatcher
{
    //Universal INFO
    public var generalInfo:GeneralInfoModel;
    public var meetingVO:MeetingVO = new MeetingVO();
    public var meetingId:String;

    public var bulletinBoardLiveMembers:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    public var xmppServices:XMPPServices;

    public var declinedParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var notJoinedParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var conferenceRoomParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var otherLocationParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    public var documentList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    public var newAttachmentList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var docsAndAttachmentsList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    public var bulletinBoardMsgList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    private var _participantList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var dismissedMeetingIDs:Array = [];
    public var visibleToastWindows:Array = [];

    public function MeetingInfoModel()
    {
        generalInfo = GeneralInfoModel.getInstance();
        xmppServices = XMPPServices.getInstance();
        _participantList.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, allParticipantsChangeHandler);
        bulletinBoardLiveMembers.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, bulletinBoardLiveMembersChangeHandler);
    }

    private static var model:MeetingInfoModel = null;

    public static function getInstance():MeetingInfoModel
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new MeetingInfoModel();
        }
        return model;
    }

    public function displayToastForThisMeeting(meetingID:Number):Boolean
    {
        //trace("model::meetingID = " + meetingID);
        var doDisplayToast:Boolean = false;
        var containsMeetingID:Boolean = false;
        //the first one
        if(dismissedMeetingIDs.length == 0)
        {
            //trace("dismissedMeetingIDs.length = 0");
            doDisplayToast = true;
            dismissedMeetingIDs.push(meetingID);
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i:int=0; i < dismissedMeetingIDs.length; i++)
            {
                //trace("dismissedMeetingIDs[" + i + "] = " + dismissedMeetingIDs[i]);
                if(meetingID == dismissedMeetingIDs[i])
                {   //this one has already been dismissed
                    doDisplayToast = false;
                    containsMeetingID = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    doDisplayToast = true;
                    containsMeetingID = false;
                }
            }

            if(containsMeetingID == false)
            {
                dismissedMeetingIDs.push(meetingID);
            }
        }
        return doDisplayToast;
    }

    public function setAllParticipants(value:ArrayCollection):void
    {
        _participantList = value;
        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.HAVE_PARTICIPANT_LIST));
        calculateGroups();
    }

    public function getParticipant(loginName:String):ParticipantVO
    {   
        for each (var item:ParticipantVO in _participantList)
        {
            if (item.loginName == loginName)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;    
    }

    private function allParticipantsChangeHandler(event:CollectionEvent):void
    {
        calculateGroups();
    }

    private function bulletinBoardLiveMembersChangeHandler(event:CollectionEvent):void
    {
        calculateGroups();
    }

    private function isInRoster( loginName:String ):Boolean { 
        for each (var newContactVO:ContactVO in model.generalInfo.allGroup)
        {
            if ( newContactVO.profileVO.email == loginName ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function calculateGroups():void
    {
        var allGroup:ArrayCollection = generalInfo.allGroup;

        var participantsRosterGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var declinedParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var notJoinedParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var conferenceRoomParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var otherLocationParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        var notDeclinedParticipantsGroup:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        for each (var item:Object in _participantList)
        {
            //because participant list contains both people and rooms, we must test to see if this is a participant
            if(item is ParticipantVO)
            {
                var xmppLoginName:String = util.formatEmailToUserName(item.loginName);
                for each (var newContactVO:ContactVO in allGroup)
                {

                    if ( item.loginName != model.generalInfo.ownerUser.loginName ) {
                        var rosterVO:RosterItemVO = newContactVO.rosterItemVO;

                        if (rosterVO.jid.node == xmppLoginName)
                        {
                            try {
                                var contactVO:ContactVO = new ContactVO();
                                //add the photo to the roster entry for each person in the meeting
                                if ( newContactVO.profileVO ) {
                                    rosterVO.photo = newContactVO.profileVO.photo;
                                    contactVO.profileVO = xmppServices.findProfile(rosterVO.jid);
                                    contactVO.profileVO = newContactVO.profileVO;
                                }
                                else {
                                    rosterVO.photo = null;
                                }

                                contactVO.rosterItemVO = rosterVO;

                            }
                            catch (e:Error) {
                                trace(e.message);
                            }

                            if (item.status == "declined")
                            {
                                declinedParticipantsGroup.addItem(contactVO);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                notDeclinedParticipantsGroup.addItem(contactVO);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }

        for each (var contact:ContactVO in notDeclinedParticipantsGroup)
        {
            var joined:Boolean = false;
            if ( contact.rosterItemVO ) {
                for each (var memberName:String in bulletinBoardLiveMembers)
                {
                    if (contact.rosterItemVO.jid.node == memberName)
                    {
                        joined = true;

                        if (contact.rosterItemVO.jid.resource == "theconfroomimsittingin"  )
                        {
                            conferenceRoomParticipantsGroup.addItem(contact);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            otherLocationParticipantsGroup.addItem(contact);
                        }
                        //dispatchEvent "DW has joined the meeting"
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!joined)
            {
                notJoinedParticipantsGroup.addItem(contact);
            }
        }

        this.notJoinedParticipantsGroup = notJoinedParticipantsGroup;
        this.declinedParticipantsGroup = declinedParticipantsGroup;
        this.otherLocationParticipantsGroup = otherLocationParticipantsGroup;
        this.conferenceRoomParticipantsGroup = conferenceRoomParticipantsGroup;
    }

    public function clearMeeting():void
    {
        meetingId = "";
        _participantList.removeAll();
        docsAndAttachmentsList.removeAll();
        documentList.removeAll();
        newAttachmentList.removeAll();
        bulletinBoardMsgList.removeAll();
        bulletinBoardLiveMembers.removeAll();
    }
    [Bindable]
    public function get participantList():ArrayCollection
    {
        return _participantList;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: is MeetinginfoModel.getInstance() a singleton?  If so, you wouldn't have to pass it at all and just use it as a singleton.  Otherwise, access it the same way in every case.

Comment: yes, binding would work in your MeetingViewStack. What you can do is add a setter inside your viewstack (make meeingInfo private) and see if the setter is called..

Comment: It is a Singleton, yes. I just thought it strange to pass it thru, that's all.

Comment: Adding a setter is a good idea, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: The setter was perfect for testing, thank you. I've udpated my question with the real issue; how to get an array collection in that model to update in the other class. Because right now it's not doing that.

Comment: IS docsAndAttachmentsList biindable? Having meetingInfo as bindable will detect changes meetingInfo but to detect changes to any properties inside meetingInfo those properties must also be bindable.

Comment: Well, I made the entire MeetingInfoModel class [Bindable].

Comment: Can you post the code? [Bindable] Class class; doesn't make and array collections inside class bindable by default.

Comment: To be clearer by code I mean the code for the MeetingInfoModel class.

Comment: I thought the [Bindable] tag did make any array collections inside bindable. Ok, this could be the issue. I've posted the class: Thank you for your continued help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see of the code so far it should work. Rather than having the whole model class bindable try to only make the properties you need bindable bindable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you have the binding the wrong way around.

At the top level it should be:

```
[Bindable] private var meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel = MeetingInfoModel.getInstance();
```

And inside the MeetingViewStack component:

```
[Bindable] public var meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel;
```

It may also depend on what properties in the MeetingInfoModel class are [Bindable].

Comment: Thank you. I'm still testing but to answer your question: The MeetingInfoModel is a public final class that extends EventDispatcher with a [Bindable] tag set on it.

Comment: You were right, thank you. The binding works just fine. I've updated my question with the real issue now: How to get an ArrayCollection that's part of "meetingInfo" to update when I add new items.